# Stopping 3 Images spinning on 1 button click

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to work out how to stop the 3 images at different times whilst pressing the handle of the fruit machine is there away i can do this using JavaScript.

```
const images = ["plum.jpg", "cherries.jpg", "pineapple.jpg", "lemon.jpg", "apple.jpg", "bananas.jpg"];

var count;
const speed = 100;

function beginShow(){
    count = 20;
   nextImage();}

function nextImage(){
changeImage("pic1");

count = count - 1;  // count down
if (count > 0)      // repeat unless we're at zero
setTimeout(function(){alert("Try Again") }, 1000); // pop up after 1 second saying try again 
changeImage("pic2");

count = count - 1;  // count down
if (count > 0)      // repeat unless we're at zero
{
    tim = setTimeout("nextImage();", 200);
}

changeImage("pic3");

count = count - 1;  // count down
if (count > 0)      // repeat unless we're at zero

{
    tim = setTimeout("nextImage();", 300);
}}

function changeImage(imageId){
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.getElementById(imageId).src =images[rand];
// changes handle from not pulled to pulled
var image = document.getElementById('Lever');
if (image.src.match("Lever2")) {
    image.src = "lever1.jpg";
} else {
    image.src = "lever2.jpg"; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a school exercise, I will not post code.

However, note this: `count` is either a global variable, and is being accessed from within a closed scope (a function). Or count is being created at run time, and being set its default value (`0`)...

Also, your setTimeout appears to be wrong...

If you intend to do an action a `x` time, then `x+1`, then `x+2`, then just concatenate the timeouts (and please, [read some documentation on MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout))

### edit:

An example that could help is as following:

```
function roll(){
   var timer1 = window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("pic1").src=images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];}, 1000);
   var timer2 = window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("pic2").src=images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];}, 2000);
   var timer3 = window.setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("pic3").src=images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: I edited the code with by adding timeouts like you suggested but now they only change once so i dont know if i've done it properly

Comment: {
  timeoutID = setTimeout(nextImage("pic3"), 3000);
 }

Comment: Please, never post code in the "comment field", edit your question, and post a formatted change there. You want to change the image 3 times correct? Then, set the timeout for `x` time, then `x+delay`time, then `x+(2*delay)` time. Also, as far as I can see, your setTimeout function is VERY unsafe, as its using `eval` on arguments (check the internet for `eval is evil`) to create a function, and you already know your own function...The main problem with what you are doing is that you dont understand the code you are running. Check that again, and make a simpler code

Comment: I want the images to change about 20 times each but the current function spins 3 images like a fruit machine and i would like them to stop 1 by 1

Comment: there are 3 images next to each other that spin about 20 times each and i want them all to start at the same time but finish at seperate times and they all connected to one button

Comment: I am guessing that the `changeImage` function does the image effects on the slots changing, and altering the image.... What you just need to do is: Start 3 timers (`x`,`x+delay`,`x+(2*delay)`), start changing images, then, at timer 1, stop image 1, at timer 2, stop image 2, at timer 3 stop image 3... DO NOT CHAIN timeouts inside themselfs, or use recursion in non-recursive ways.

Comment: could you give me an example as im seriously confused :)

Comment: Please, check the edit.... and please, read AGAIN the documentation: read this quote: `"Passing a string instead of a function to setTimeout() suffers from the same hazards as using eval. "`